# Missing required parameters error in production but works locally

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-forge

This is a strange one I've been fighting for the last 12ish hours. On my production app I'm getting the following error:

```
Missing required parameters for [Route: tasks.update] [URI: tasks/{task}]. (View: /home/forge/DOMAIN/resources/views/tasks/index.blade.php)
```

My form action:

```html
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('tasks.update', ['task' => $task->task_id]) }}">
```

My controller method:

```php
 public function update(Task $task, Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->priority_score != $task->job->priority)
        {
            $task->job()->update([
                'priority' => $request->priority_score
            ]);

            return back()->with('success', 'Priority score successfully updated!');
        }

        $task->update($request->all());

        return back()->with('success', 'Task successfully updated!');
    }
```

And my routes/web.php

```php
Route::post('/tasks/{task_id}', 'TaskController@update')->name('tasks.update');
Route::resource('tasks', 'TaskController');
```

I moved the update method to its own route in the hopes that might help the production issue, since it also works locally, but it did not.

I've cleared caches, run dump-autoload, all to no avail.

Thoughts?

Comment: Hey there! I can't understand from your code why it would fail.. Some clues to guide you though: `$task->task_id`  seems weird maybe `$task->id` instead? From your Controller try `public function update(Request $request, $task)` ? set .env variable the same as development for debugging purposes? As mentioned, the extra route would just make things worse - better remove it

Answer (score 0):

Your given resource route already provide a route format like:

```
Route::post('/tasks/{task_id}', 'TaskController@update');
```

You can find it in your route list. So these two routes might create a duplicate issue, i guess. You can try changing your single route like following:

```
Route::post('/task/{task_id}', 'TaskController@update')->name('task.update');
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: That's why I added the single route, just for kicks. The resource route works fine locally, along with the rest of the code, it just wasn't working in production. 

Another user on Laracasts suggested they had a similar problem after upgrading to 7. This error first occured after I pushed the 7 upgrade, but I rolled it back so our users could still use the app. However, the error remained even though the Laravel version had reverted back to 6.4.x.

I'm going to check out my upgrade branch and try some things. I'll post back when I found out more. Thanks!

Comment: yah, sometimes in local, Laravel ignore some cases, but in production it wants perfection. There are many cases you will find working fine locally, but not in production...

Comment: There was a set of ```$tasks``` that don't have a ```task_id```. The code is now checking for that and works in production. Frustrating that it's allowed locally and not in production but at least it was finally found. Thanks again for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Inspecting the page with dev tools showed there was a set of $tasks that don't have a task_id. I wrote code to check for the null value and it now works in production.